# Cache array of objects in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, caching, redis

I have a schools social network, every school has a a number of dashboards that the students can post in it, since I don't want to go to the database every time a student want to see a dashboard I thought to build a cache system for the schools, at the beginning I created a module that creates a hash map to hold the School objects, in every School object I have a similar hash map for the dashboards and the same in every dashboard to hold the Post objects (I don't know if this is a common way or even acceptable at all), recently while searching for another approach I read about redis which is a key-value store system in memory.

My question: is it possible to achieve what I want in redis (since its a key-value store system) or even any other cache module or simply to stuck with what I have in hands? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like [flat](https://github.com/hughsk/flat) could help you store it in Redis

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use redis as cache system. This provide various data structure including hashmap, list, set, etc. There is need for proper structuring of data in redis and there you go with high performance asd efficiency.
For reference: https://redis.io/topics/data-types